# Load routes.yaml in external bundle without config. in project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

With Symfony 4, I want to load `routes.yaml` in my custom external Bundle. I created class extended `Load` but it's not loaded ( Resource : https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html#more-advanced-loaders )

```
namespace GaylordP\FineUploaderBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null): RouteCollection
    {
        $routes = new RouteCollection();

        $importedRoutes = $this->import(
            '@FineUploaderBundle/Resources/config/routes.yaml',
            'yaml'
        );

        $routes->addCollection($importedRoutes);
        dump($routes); // not executed
        exit; // not executer
        return $routes;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null): bool
    {
        return 'advanced_extra' === $type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add the import in the main existing `config/routes.yaml` file :

```
fineuploaderbundle:
    resource: "@FineUploaderBundle/Resources/config/routes.yaml"
```

Comment: it is not possible to load bundle routes automatically, without having to add a configuration to the project ?

Comment: No, not using code. However, you could use Flex recipes to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand ... :/ ... I want to load route without configuration in my project (configuration only inside bundle), it's possible .

Comment: Well, no it is not possible without configuration in your project nor using code in your bundle. The only way to auto-configure your project is using Flex recipes : https://github.com/symfony/recipes

Answer (score 1):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#routing

> Routing is never automatically imported in Symfony. If you want to
>   include the routes from any bundle, then they must be manually
>   imported from somewhere in your application (e.g. config/routes.yaml).