# Symfony bundle - generate configuration file

Tags: symfony, bundle

I'm working on creating a Symfony bundle, so far so good, but I'm running into a problem when I want to generate a configuration/route file when installing the bundle. When I install the bundle I would like it to generate the configuration files in the app and not have to add them by hand.
Could someone help me please?

I tried to load yaml / xml files within my Extension file, I tried to import via services.xml but I can't make it working.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for recipes? See https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony/flex-recipes

Comment: Or does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595101/how-write-a-symfony-flex-recipe-for-a-new-bundle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load routes.yaml in external bundle without config. in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401651/load-routes-yaml-in-external-bundle-without-config-in-project)

Comment: I’ll try to do with recipes, I hadn't thought of that, thank you for your quicks replies both :) I’ll let you know how it’s going !

Comment: Hello, how did you solve the issue?